# A statistical test for distinguishing between two possible processes

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am researching a physical domain where I know one of two processes is taking place. I have variables X,Y which should display a different correlation depending on the process taking place. X is set, Y is observed. I want to test my observations to know which of the two processes is taking place.

Process A should yield $Y(X) = K (constant)$

Process B should yield $Y(X) = [A*sin(4*X+\phi+22.5)+B]/[C*sin(2*X+\phi)+D]$ (pseudo-sinusoidal)

[image]

A,B,C,D,$\phi$ are unknown constants. $\phi$ represents a possible shift of the horizontal axis

Here is my data which I think looks much more like process B than A but I want to give it a statistical significance.

[image]

Comment: These don't look like "distributions" in any conventional sense: it looks instead like you're collecting x-y data.  One important guide to their analysis is a description of how they were collected: for instance, are both variables observed simultaneously or do you set one and observe the other?  What do you know or can assume about the nature, magnitude, and distribution of variations from the expected curves?

Comment: @whuber, I guess my terminology is not right. X is set and Y is observed. Trying new X values is not always possible and therefore I have some gaps. The magnitude of Y should be in the range of -5 to +10 for process B and 0 to 10 for A.

Comment: Thank you.  What would be most helpful, though, is given any value of $X$, suppose the theoretical value of $Y$ on the correct curve is $f(X).$ You observe some value $Y$ corresponding to that $X.$ Your data show so much scatter that it's not plausible they all fall exactly on the graph of $f,$ so we must assume $Y-f(X)$ can be nonzero.  *How far from zero can this residual be?*  What is the expected statistical distribution of the residuals? If you don't know, do you at least know (or postulate) mechanisms to explain this scatter? Knowledge of those mechanisms can be a helpful guide.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this problem as a nonlinear regression analysis, where you posit the regression function in process $B$ along with some appropriate error distribution.  For example, if you assume homoskedastic errors then you might use the model:

$$Y_i = \frac{a \cdot \sin(4x_i + \phi + 22.5) + b}{c \cdot \sin(2x_i + \phi) + d} + \varepsilon_i
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad
\varepsilon_1, ..., \varepsilon_n \sim \text{IID N}(0, \sigma^2).$$

Process $A$ is a special case of this process when $a = c = 0$.  Thus, you can test whether the additional complexity of process $B$ is required by testing the hypotheses:

$$H_0: a = c = 0
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
H_A: a \neq 0 \text{ or } c \neq 0.$$

If there is significant evidence in favour of the alternative hypothesis (at your chosen significance level) then this means that there is significant evidence in favour of process $B$.  You can use the `nls` function in `R` to fit nonlinear regression models, and then you will be able to conduct the required hypothesis test.

Comment: I think it would be important to discuss the inapplicability of this approach when the observations are correlated, which still appears to be a possibility--the OP hasn't yet disclosed enough information about the experiment and the measurement process to know.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  I took his reference to correlation as referring to correlation between $x_i$ and $y_i$.  In any case, I would think you could probably check for IID error terms using standard diagnostic plots for the nonlinear regression.

Comment: I think you would also want to include diagnostics for the alternative regression (the constant model) to demonstrate that the residuals could not be explained by strong correlations among the errors.  Although in the given case it's visually obvious which regression is correct, as a general proposition such analyses might be essential.

Comment: The constant regression is a nested model, so I would not think it is necessary for separate diagnostic plots.  For example, when you do standard linear regression, you only produce diagnostic plots for the full model; you still test hypotheses on the coefficient parameters without producing separate diagnostics for those nested models.  Happy to be convinced to the contrary if I'm wrong.

Comment: I think you might not be considering the possibility of strongly correlated residuals.